# Randomize string characters

Tags: php

I'm looking for a function to change the characters order in a string.

For example, I have this string : `"How are you?"` , calling the function with this string as parameter would return something like: `"wuayero Ho?"` or something similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP has a handy [**str_shuffle**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php) function for that